# Why does my ajax request strip out a '\' backslash character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, razor-2

I'm calling a rest endpoint with ajax that is like this. It takes two params **user** and **permission**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: "/app/Rest/4.0/UserManagement/AddPermissionToUser",
    data: {
        username: encodeURI(user),
        permissionName: encodeURI(permission)
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

In the javascript, let's say may **user** is something like **domain\user1**, the ajax request strips out the backslash character. Originially I didn't have the encodeUri()'s in there

One more curious thing is that if I manually stick this url in my browser encoding it like this **domain%5Cuser1** it works as expected. I am in IE 11, is the browser stripping this off, or is it a problem with jQuery? Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery's ajax does not strip out any slashes, and it encodes the data for you so you can get rid of those encodeURI functions. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @adeneo Good to know. The certainly rules out a whole slew of problems that I don't want to investigate.

Comment: @matrixugly FYI, even if you needed to encode the values you should have used `encodeURIComponent`. `encodeURI` is to encode full URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\` may be seen as being used to escape special characters server-side.

Try passing a string like `domain\\user1`, to see if it comes through as a single slash.

It's possible there is a better solution, but we would need to see what you're doing with the string in your server-side code.

Comment: I really doubt. Escape characters are considered only in string literals, not when the value is already a string in memory.

Comment: I'll try hardcoding the value a couple different ways and let you know the results. Technically I'm building part of this out in Razor w/ MVC 4. I need to make sure the server side code is building the literal strings correctly.

Comment: Turns out that was the problem. In my server side razor code, I did username.Replace("\\","\\\\") so that js string literal was correct.

MVC Razor username = "domain\\\\user";
JS username = "domain\\user";

Comment: Added `razor-2` tag to the question for future users.